# How to change owner and permissions of registry key using cmd or powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-10

Is it possible to change owner and permissions of registry key without any third party utility only in-build windows tools, like cmd or powershell?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: see a question on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/28931/how-to-set-permissions-on-registry-keys-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. 
Yes. 
There are .exe's (that you can use with or without PowerShell) and cmdlets to use.

It's your choice.

Built-in cmdlets that do exactly this.  Use the help files to see examples

```
Get-Command -Name '*acl*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Get-ADUser).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-Acl-Full
Get-help -Name Get-Acl-Online
Get-help -Name Get-Acl-Examples


(Get-Command -Name Set-ADUser).Parameters
Get-help -Name Set-Acl-Full
Get-help -Name Set-Acl-Online
Get-help -Name Set-Acl-Examples
```